# Unexpected SyntaxError: invalid syntax in nested loops

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error, nested-loops, iterable

Why it gives SyntaxError: invalid syntax in the second last line `for jindx in xrange(1, 10):`?
It happens with any command I try

```
import numpy as np
from __future__ import division

def olsgmm(lhv, rhv, lags, wight):
    global Exxprim
    global inner
    if len(rhv[:,]) != len(lhv[:,]):
        print ("olsgmm: leftand right sides must have same number of rows. Currentlyrows are:")
        len(lhv)
        len(rhv)
    T = len(lhv[:,])
    N = len(lhv[:,1])
    K = len(rhv[:,1])
    sebv = np.zeros()
    Exxprim = np.linalg.inv((rhv.T * rhv)/T)
    bv = np.linalg.lstsq(rhv, lhv)
    if (len(weight[:,]) == 1 & len(lhv[:,1]) > 1):
        weight = weight * np.ones(len(lhv[:,1]),)
    if (len(lags[:,]) == 1 & len(lhv[:,1]) > 1):
        lags = lags * np.ones(len(lhv[:,1]),)
    if weight == -1: 
        sebv = float('nan')
        R2v = float('nan')
        R2vadj = float('nan')
        v = float('nan')
        F = float('nan')
    else:
        errv = lhv - rhv * bv
        s2 = np.mean(np.power(err, 2))
        vary = lhv - np.ones(T, 1)
        vary = np.mean(np.power(vary, 2))
        R2v = (1 - np.divide(s2, vary))
        R2adj = (1 - (np.divide(s2, vary)) * (T - 1)/(T - K)).T
        for indx in xrange(1, N + 1):
            err = errv[:,indx]
            if (weight[indx] == 0 | weight[indx] == 1):
                inner = (np.multiply(rhv, (err * np.ones(1,k))).T * (np.multiply(rhv, np.ones(1, K)))/T
                for jindx in xrange(1, 10):
                    inneradd = ([np.multiply(rhv, err) for j in xrange(1, T - jindx)] * np.ones(1, k)).T
```

In addition to this when I run the `numpy.linalg.lstsq()` in line 16, rhv and lhv are both K x N matrix (rhv first row is intercept and second row is regressor), it gives me 4 N x N array of coefficients. Does anyone know how to perform a correct joint output ls regression so as to end up with 2 K x N array of coefficients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed out a `)` on the preceding line:

```
inner = (np.multiply(rhv, (err * np.ones(1,k))).T * (np.multiply(rhv, np.ones(1, K)))/T
#       ^           2     3             4   432     2           3            4    432  ?
```

That outer parentheses pair would be redundant however; you don't need to group a top-level expression. There are a further two pairs of redundant parentheses; the following should work just fine:

```
np.multiply(rhv, err * np.ones(1, k)).T * np.multiply(rhv, np.ones(1, K)) / T
```

Because Python allows for logical lines to span multiple physical lines of source code by enclosing them in parentheses (or square brackets or curly braces) the `for` line is part of the offending line as there is no closing `)` found yet.

So, rule of thumb: when you get a `SyntaxError` that doesn't appear to make sense, check the preceding lines for a missing closing brace.